# How to custom edit_user_path with nice URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic, permalinks

I'm adding a nav menu in `application.html.erb` which navigate users in authlogic. All routers like: :logout, :register and :login seems working with custom paths.

```
match 'account/login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
match 'account/logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
match 'register' => 'users#new', :as => :register
```

Here is nav menu:

```
<% if current_user %>
    <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(current_user.id)%> <%=h current_user.firstname %>
    <%= link_to "Logout", :logout %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Register", :register %> | 
    <%= link_to "Login", :login %>
<% end %>
```

But edit_user_path is transferring me to `/users/:id/edit`. How do I make the nice URL for this path. I would like to make it `/account/edit`. It also need to disable this path `/users/:id/edit` to prevent user from requesting another user ID which doesnt belong to him/her. It should throw a 404 page is perfect.

Current paths in the nav menu:

Logout: `/account/logout`

Login:  `/account/login`

Register: `/register`

I would love to have another path for edit_user_path:

Edit profile: `/account/edit`

Is there any way I can simply use edit_user_path(current_user.id) and the path automatically transfers me to /account/edit and disable id request.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

**[Updated]** This is my /config/router.rb

```
Appcatous::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, :user_sessions

  match "account" => "users#show", :as => :account
  match 'account/login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
  match 'account/logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
end
```

users.rb model is very simple:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic

  validates :firstname, :presence => true  
  validates :lastname,  :presence => true 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you included all the routes in question - which means also the routes for the users. Did you create those with:

```
resources :users
```

In case you did, you'll have to disable that command and recreate just the routes you need manually with (example!):

```
match 'account/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_user
```

or whatever your controller is named. That way you'll get your "/account/edit" - however, you'll also have no way to transfer the user id that way. That one you'll have to transfer by other means, like through a variable stored in a cookie or a session.
The latter method is the usual way of remembering user authentification anyway.

Comment: Hi, I already did it, but I don't like it that way. I would prevent users from requesting ID as well. Using custom router seems to be simple solution but user still can access /users/:id/edit. My question is if we can still use **edit_user_path(current_user.id)** in template code but the path changed.

Comment: If you use custom routes instead of the 'resources :users' then, no, user won't be able to access /users/:id/edit. And you can't have it both ways - either you have the ID in the URL or you don't. But in the latter case you'll have to transport it by session or cookies. http is a stateless protocol, after all.

Comment: hmm, it seems `current_user.id` won't work anymore without `resources :users`

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm flying a bit in the dark here. It would be very helpful if we knew what your config/routes.rb and your app/controller/users.rb actually looked like.

Comment: Hi Rhywden, I updated the code but they are all very simple though.

Comment: Well, as I said: If you're using the automatic route creation you have to use what it serves you. Either you use 'resources :users' and don't have a pretty url or you set everything manually. That will break authlogic, though, since it obviously relies on the automatic routes. However, did you do a test to see if authlogic prevents users from accessing other users' profiles?

Comment: The only problem now is prevent users from requesting id when editing profile. I think manually adding route will be the simplest solution for now. About authlogic, there is nothing broken since it's using another model user_sessions.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the gem ["devise"](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) . No easily manipulable ids in the url there. That's the one I use for user authentification